# Parse pictures in images to text in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ocr

I am just wondering if there is any DLLs or features in VB.Net 2008 that I could use to parse a picture of text to text (for example, a screenshot), assuming the text are in very recognizable format (i.e., not like CAPTCHA type of text).

Answer (score 1):

If it is *incredibly* readable, an unaltered, pure, screenshot, then the *easiest* (but probably slowest) way is to draw each letter (using `Graphics.DrawString`) on to a bitmap and compare that, pixel by pixel, against each pixel. This could be reasonably quick considering how OCR is, and it would almost certainly give a 100% accuracy rate. Even better would be if you're trying to recognize text in a certain area, reducing the search area and increasing speed several times, and even better if the text is in a fixed-width format and you know the font size or can figure it out by searching a small area - you can skip the entire block when a letter is recognized!

If you don't know how to do this type of image manipulation, that's OK. Look at `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` on MSDN to start out, then move on to the speed section and look for examples using `LockBits`.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not THAT easy to read, it is more like a bunch of scanned files that I now have to convert to text, since those are scanned copies, they are not that good to read and the font could be different...

Answer (score 1):

By far and away your best bet on this one is to buy some OCR software to do it for you. Here's another option, although you'll have to wait:
http://www.labnol.org/software/convert-scanned-pdf-images-to-text-with-google-ocr/5158/

Comment: quite troublesome, but I guess this is the best I can get? That sucks though, I　will have to set up a website for it as well...